# Labeling features with numeric field which has null values and another text field, showing both fields even when there's null values using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.3

I'm labelling features with an simple expression to show [Number] + [Code], however, I have some null values in "Number".

When I use this expression it only labels the features with both number and code, however, I need it to display both, columns even if there is no value.

i.e. if there's no number display only display the code, if there's a number and a code, display both.

Do I need an Advanced level license to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do with using [label classes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm).

Define two classes with SQL query:

```
Number is null
```

and

```
Number is not null
```

Then label each of the classes with the fields needed.

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat. It also didn't help that I had the "label features in this class" turned off when I'd tried something similar the first time.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with an advanced label expression.

For example, I've got a label expression that will take 2 fields and label with whichever of the fields is present, or both. You could do something like the following:
[image]

Important notes about the code provided:

- Obviously you would have to change the code to use your own field names
- In the Label Expression dialog, you have to switch the parser to Python, or write your own label expression in your chosen language.
- You have to make sure the "Advanced" check box is selected/turned on.
- The provided code will actually create stacked labels (Field_1 on one line and Field_2 on the next line).  If you want it to all be on one line separated by a space, you can change the `"\n"` at the end of the 4th line to just be a space in quotes `" "`

Code provided below so you can copy past instead of re-typing from screen shot:

```
def FindLabel ( [FIELD_1], [FIELD_2] ):
  lbl = ""
  if [FIELD_1] <> None:
    lbl += str([FIELD_1]) + "\n"
  if [FIELD_2] <> None:
    lbl += str([FIELD_2])
  return lbl
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything in it for you.